# Using python to access the attributes of features within the current extent?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, extents

The script I'm writing requires a specific attribute of the building polygon that the data frame extent is currently focused on. Is there a way to grab this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ArcGIS 10, you can use arcpy.mapping to do this. It would look something like:

```
mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
dataframe = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc, mapdoc.activeView)[0]
extent = dataframe.extent
```

You can then pass the extent in as parameters to GP tools etc.

Comment: After you've got the active extent, you can get feature attributes by using Select Layer By Location (http://tinyurl.com/298khqo)

Comment: Where would I input the active extent in this tool?

SelectLayerByLocation_management (in_layer, {overlap_type}, {select_features}, {search_distance}, {selection_type})

For overlap_type, I'm using COMPLETELY_WITHIN, but according to the documentation, I can only select features from the in_layer that are completely within a polygon, not an extent.

Comment: As far as I know, it should still work as an input there. Try it out.

Comment: The extent you process over is an ArcGIS environment variable. You can set that with python before you run whatever other tools you'll use. See http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000009000000